# "jvm" appearing everywhere while generating the markdown format documentation using Dokka

Tags: android, kotlin, dokka

Whenever I generate markdown format (GFM or Jekyll) using dokka, it generates the documentation with "[jvm]" tag appearing everywhere in every field as show in the screenshot below. Does anyone has any idea why this is happening and what can I do to fix it. I'm using dokka version 1.7.20 on a pure kotlin project, and I have just added "id("org.jetbrains.dokka") version ("1.7.20")" in the Gradle file.[image]